# UWP AutoSuggestBox Customize Icons

Tags: uwp

I am using AutoSuggestBox in my app, and I prefer to make the following changes.

1. In using QueryIcon=Find, I can see the search on the right most. Can I align it to Left ( similar to edge search window)
2. Can I customize the "clear all" button. I want to use different icons, at different times, depending on some actions in the SuggestBox.

Can you please point to what are my options...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is apply a new style, you can find the default style from [AutoSuggestBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx). So if you want align `QueryButton` to left, change the layout.

Answer (score 3):

AutoSuggestBox is a sealed control, so you cannot retemplate it to customize it much beyond properties are made available to you. There are a number of resources (see generic.xaml and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox)) that you can override to, for example, change the size of the icon:

```
<x:Double x:Key="AutoSuggestBoxIconFontSize">12</x:Double>
```

Theoretically, you can also crawl the visual tree to retrieve certain elements and modify them in code-behind, but this can be messy, introduce bugs, and cause you to take a performance hit.

You *can* set TextBoxStyle on AutoSuggestBox and set it to a custom TextBox, where you may be able to manipulate some of the XAML to meet your needs, but you would need to create a new full style for each variation you need. The downside of this is that because you need multiple instances of the entire TextBox template, you will take a performance hit and it will prevent you from receiving bug fixes and updates to the TextBox style for free in the future.

You can also implement your own AutoSuggestBox with any custom functionality you like. This may be a more complex solution, but it might be the least hacky and most performant option.

I would recommend *not* making some of these changes, though, since they would be inconsistent with the rest of the platform and may confuse users. In Edge, there *is* a search glyph on the left, but the glyph is not the same as the search *button* in the AutoSuggetsBox. In fact, it does not appear that Edge uses the AutoSuggestBox control, but rather has their own custom implementation.

Comment: No you will not take a performance hit when you simply try to create a style for the control.

Comment: Whether you put those styles in App.xaml or Page.Resources, it will need to load at some point, which _will_ introduce a performance hit. The more complex the style, the bigger the hit. They want to use different icons at different times, which implies multiple copies of the full TextBox control template, since you cannot manipulate the glyph or position of the FontIcon in the template without overriding the entire control template, it would be a relatively large hit compared to a style that does not override the control template or overriding the template of a simpler control, like a Button.

Comment: I have apps that use more than a hundred of custom styles with many svg/path icons and storyboard animations, and I never for once have noticed any startup delay because of them. You can try including massive resource dictionaries to an app and it will load just as fast.

Comment: Ultimately, we are talking in milliseconds here, but depending on how/where you add the styles and how you consume them there [may be optimizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-xaml-loading) to help limit impact.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link. Looks like XBF2 is automatically supported in UWP app now? And it kinda backs up my point? :)